# Position with pdfpages

Tags: pdfpages

I have a landscape A5 pdf, which I would like to include on top of the page. However, with this MWE the file is centered:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf{a5.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\includepdf[offset=0 370]{a5.pdf}
```

was the solution (thanks to `texdoc pdfpages`)