# Combining LaTeX files with different formatting

Tags: input

I am trying to compile a teaching portfolio of various LaTeX files. I have a main file and want to call the other files while keeping the formatting of the other files. I do want to put my name in the footer of every page after the first page (table of contents) of the document though.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

My main file is currently:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone,geometry,lscape}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{TylerClarkCommands}
\title{Teaching Portfolio}
\author{Tyler Clark}
\date{Fall 2014}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{CV}
\newgeometry{left=1in,bottom=1.3in,top=1.5in,right=1in}
\input{../../../../Resume_CV/ThomasTylerClarkCV}
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Teaching Philosophy}
\begin{center}
Teaching Philosophy
\end{center}
 \input{TeachingPhilosophy}
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Mathematics for Calculus Course Plan}
\begin{center}
Mathematics for Calculus Course Plan
\end{center}
\input{MathforCalcCoursePlan}
\end{document}

Now for the CV, I have something like

\documentclass{article}
\oddsidemargin=.15in
\evensidemargin=.15in
\textwidth=6in
\topmargin=-.5in
\textheight=9.1in
\parindent=0in
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
{\Large NAME} \\[.5pc]
SCHOOL \\
ADDRESS\\
ADDRESS\\
CONTACT $\;$\\
\end{center}
{\large \bf Education} \\*[-.8pc]
\underline{\hspace{6in}} \\
\\
%{\bf School stuff} \\
%Anticipate completion and defense of dissertation in May. \\
%\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: The principal problem is that you can't have  `\@onlypreamble` commands like `\documentclass`, `\usepackage` etc. and `\begin{document}` more than one, so a direct inclusion involves some work. It's possible, with some efforts, however, if your files to be included are not to complicated

Comment: The `combine` package might help: http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/combine/combine.pdf

Comment: Christian, any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Compile the documents separately, include the pdf-files as pictures in a master file, that adds the footer, seems to be the easiest solution.

See e.g. [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118052/position-with-pdfpages) or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117960/header-and-page-numbers-with-pdfpages) question that includes external documents with pdfpages.

Comment: Do you mean this serious? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer why not?

Comment: if you would mention the `pdfpages` package, and link to a question or two on this site that demonstrates its use, I'd vote for your answer :)

Comment: You could improve this answer by explaining how to use `pagecommand={}` to include the footer with the OP's name on each page.